# Change position of container on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the position of my elements on mobile devices. I got a container with 2 `col-sm-6`. One includes an image and the other on a text. Underneath is another container with the same values, except that the elements are mirrored to the container above it. On mobile devices it's handling them then in this sequence. 1. Image 2. Text 3. Text 4. Image. Is it possible to have on mobile devices 1. Image 2. Text 3. Image 4. Text?

First Container

```html
<div class="nm-row nm-row-boxed vc_row wpb_row nm-row-flex nm-row-col-middle  vc_custom_1551441311893">
  <div class="description-img nm_column wpb_column vc_column_container col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center">

          <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
            <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="720" height="563" src="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="" srcset="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg 720w, https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451-350x274.jpg 350w, https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451-680x532.jpg 680w"
                sizes="(max-width: 720px) 100vw, 720px"></div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description-headline-container nm_column wpb_column vc_column_container col-sm-6 vc_custom_1551439380195">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <h3 style="color: #ffffff;text-align: left" class="vc_custom_heading description-headline">Beste Materialien für höchsten Komfort</h3>
        <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 15px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>

        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p style="color: #fff;">Die Matratze unserer Box-Betten besteht aus einem viskoelastischen Schaumstoff, der sich dem Körper Ihres Hundes optimal anpasst. Stabile Seitenteile stützen den Kopf und sorgen für Geborgenheit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
              elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="nm-row nm-row-boxed vc_row wpb_row nm-row-flex nm-row-col-middle  vc_custom_1551441330021">
  <div class="description-headline-container nm_column wpb_column vc_column_container col-sm-6 vc_custom_1551439380195">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <h3 style="color: #ffffff;text-align: left" class="vc_custom_heading description-headline">Beste Materialien für höchsten Komfort</h3>
        <div class="vc_empty_space" style="height: 15px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>

        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p style="color: #fff;">Die Matratze unserer Box-Betten besteht aus einem viskoelastischen Schaumstoff, der sich dem Körper Ihres Hundes optimal anpasst. Stabile Seitenteile stützen den Kopf und sorgen für Geborgenheit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
              elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa.</p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="description-img nm_column wpb_column vc_column_container col-sm-6">
    <div class="vc_column-inner">
      <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center">

          <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
            <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img width="720" height="563" src="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="" srcset="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg 720w, https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451-350x274.jpg 350w, https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451-680x532.jpg 680w"
                sizes="(max-width: 720px) 100vw, 720px"></div>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

I found a website where they handle it the way i also would, but i'm not sure how to [image: How it should be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, definitely! `order` is perfect for this. Along with a 'only on mobile' `media` query - you should be good to go.

I've created some CSS here and inserted a simplified version of your HTML so that you can hopefully see how it's working and apply it to your code. :-)

```css
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .first {
    order: 1;
  }
  .second {
    order: 2;
  }
  .third {
    order: 4;
  }
  .fourth {
    order: 3;
  }
}



/*Just for the example here*/
img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.col-12 {
  background: #A9A9A9;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Including Bootstrap just for this example -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 first">
    <img src="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 second">
    <h3>Beste Materialien für höchsten Komfort</h3>
    <p>Die Matratze unserer Box-Betten besteht aus einem viskoelastischen Schaumstoff, der sich dem Körper Ihres Hundes optimal anpasst. Stabile Seitenteile stützen den Kopf und sorgen für Geborgenheit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
      elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 third">
    <h3>Beste Materialien für höchsten Komfort</h3>
    <p>Die Matratze unserer Box-Betten besteht aus einem viskoelastischen Schaumstoff, der sich dem Körper Ihres Hundes optimal anpasst. Stabile Seitenteile stützen den Kopf und sorgen für Geborgenheit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
      elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor aenean massa.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 fourth">
    <img src="https://www.amaoni.de/wp-content/uploads/mc_c02-009-01-m_sleep_feltro_boxbed_grey_2-451.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear it! :-)