# Change/Move Container Position On Mobile View Site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

i want to make the img at mobile view is beside the text

in the desktop view its gonna me like this
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzO17.png)

and i want for the mobile view
[Mobile View I Need To Move The Image Follow The Direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI92G.png)

heres my snippet for this section in html side

```
<div class="col-md-6 left-50">
                            <div class="fes2-main-text-cont">
                                <div class="title-fs-45">
                                    PT. Balga Bersaudara Manunggal<br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="line-3-100"></div>
                                <div class="fes2-text-cont">
                                    Global Rent<br>
                                    Mining Support
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-30">
                                    <a class="button medium thin hover-dark" href="pt_balga/pt-balga.html">More Info</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 right-50 wow fadeInLeft">

                            <div class="ads-img-cont hide-0-800">
                                <img src="balgas/1x/Asset_1.png" alt="img">
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

now im hiding the img because its ruin in mobile devices you can saw at the class of the image says `hide-0-800`
what should i do if i want to make it like what i want ?

i have been try some code at internet and some code here [stackoverflow order solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54944431/change-position-of-container-on-mobile-devices) and its not solve my problem, i expect the img can be shown side by side not before or after the text container

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .row {
        position: relative;
    }

    .col-md-6 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .fes2-main-text-cont {
        padding-left: 30%; /* Here make distanc */
    }

    .ads-img-cont {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fes2-main-text-cont">
            <div class="title-fs-45">PT. Balga Bersaudara Manunggal<br></div>
            <div class="line-3-100"></div>
            <div class="fes2-text-cont">Global Rent<br>Mining Support</div>
            <div class="mt-30">
                <a class="button medium thin hover-dark" href="pt_balga/pt-balga.html">More Info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ads-img-cont hide-0-800">
        <img src="balgas/1x/Asset_1.png" alt="img">
    </div>
</div>
```